# Visual Studio 2015 - Xamarin build error

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'va a fresh installation of VS 2015 with Xamarin, but when I try to build a simple "Hello World" App i receive this errors

[image]

I've also tried to repair VS 2015 installation.. but nothing. Any Idea?

Comment: I had the same issue. Deleted bin and obj folders and worked again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, usualy clean solution helps.
And you can delete content of Resource.Designer.cs and rebuild.
If this dont help update to different version of xamarin in nuget and try again...

Comment: i dont know if it would help but are you loged in with xamarin acount in VS? if yes than try to log out, restart VS and login again.